# HDFS fails to start with Hadoop 3.2 : bash v3.2+ is required

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop3

I'm building a small Hadoop cluster composed of 2 nodes : 1 master + 1 worker. I'm using the latest version of Hadoop (3.2) and everything is executed by the *root* user. In the installation process, I've been able to `hdfs namenode -format`. Next step is to start the HDFS daemon with `start-dfs.sh`.

```
$ start-dfs.sh                  
Starting namenodes on [master]
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry.
Starting datanodes
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry.
Starting secondary namenodes [master]
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry.
```

Here's the generated logs in the journal:

```
$ journalctl --since "1 min ago"
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-08-29 11:12:27 CEST, end at Thu 2019-08-29 11:46:40 CEST. --
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3329]: (to root) root on pts/0
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3329]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3329]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3334]: (to root) root on pts/0
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3334]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3334]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3389]: (to root) root on pts/0
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3389]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Aug 29 11:46:40 master su[3389]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
```

As I'm using *Zsh* (with *Oh-my-Zsh*), I logged into a bash console to give it a try. Sadly, I get the same result. In fact, this error happens for all `sbin/start-*.sh` scripts. However, the `hadoop` and `yarn` commands work like a charm.

Since I didn't find much information on this error on the Internet, here I am. Would be glad to have any advice!

---

#### Other technical details

Operating system info:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

$ uname -srm       
Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64 x86_64
```

Available Java versions (tried with both):

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java          1111      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java          1111      manual mode
```

Some ENV variables you might be interested in:

```
$ env
USER=root
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
TERM=rxvt-unicode
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
ZSH=/root/.oh-my-zsh
```

Output of the Hadoop executable:

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.2.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r e97acb3bd8f3befd27418996fa5d4b50bf2e17bf
Compiled by sunilg on 2019-01-08T06:08Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum d3f0795ed0d9dc378e2c785d3668f39
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar
```

My Zsh and Bash installation:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

# only available in a console using *bash*
$ echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}
5 0 3 1 release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: It's Debian 10 and kernel 4.19. I've updated my post accordingly ;)

Comment: I just added the output of `journalctl`

Comment: Can you please post the output of `echo ${BASH_VERSINFO}`

Comment: `echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}`

Comment: I pasted the output of this command in the post. Will respond to your answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use a different user (e.g. *hadoop*) instead of *root*.

---

I found the solution but not the deep understanding on what is going on. Despite how sad I can be, here's the solution I found:

Running with *root* user:

```
$ start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [master]
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry.
Starting datanodes
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry.
Starting secondary namenodes [master_bis]
bash v3.2+ is required. Sorry
```

Then I created a *hadoop* user and gave this user privileges on the Hadoop installation (R/W access). After logging in with this new user I have the following output for the command that caused me some troubles:

```
$ start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [master]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [master_bis]
```

Moreover, I noticed that processes created by `start-yarn.sh` were not listed in the output of `jps` while using Java 11. Switching to Java 8 solved my problem (don't forget to update all `$JAVA_HOME` variables, both in `/etc/environment` and `hadoop-env.sh`).

Success \o/. However, I'd be glad to understand why the *root* user cannot do this. I know it's a bad habit to use *root* but in an experimental environment this is not of our interest to have a clean "close-to" production environment. Any information about this will be kindly appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

to change the default shell back to bash